# PySpark too slow in Google Cloud Dataproc

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I deployed a PySpark ML model into a Google Cloud Dataproc cluster and it was running for over an hour, but my data is about 800 MB.

Is there anything being needed to declare as master on my SparkSession? I set the default option 'local'.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a `local` deploy mode option to `SparkContext` it executes your application locally on a single VM, to avoid this you should not pass any options in the [`SparkContext` constructor](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#SparkContext--) - it will use pre-configured properties by Dataproc and run your application on YARN utilizing all cluster resources/nodes.